# VIM E518: Unknown option: dark

Tags: vim

I am configuring my vim colorscheme with these in my .vimrc.

```
 "Color scheme  
 syntax enable  
 set background = dark  
 colorscheme solarized
```

When I open a file with Vim, it reports:

```
Error detected while processing /home/user/.vimrc:  
line    3:  
E518: Unknown option: dark  
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

But it works like the picture:
[dark background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyPAX.jpg)

Beacuse when I comment it in .vimrc:

```
 "set background = dark
```

the monitor is like this:[commented dark background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apOIQ.jpg).
I want to know why this happen and how to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Valid syntax for `:set`:

```
set option=value
set option= value
```

Valid syntax for `:let`:

```
let variable=value
let variable= value
let variable =value
let variable = value
```

It is recommended to always use the same syntax for consistency. I use:

```
set option=value
let variable = value
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove your space around your `=` and you should be good

```
set background=dark
```

Answer (score 2):

i just changed the syntax and it worked

```
colorscheme blue
```

and it work too

```
:colorscheme blue
```